# How do I find detectable and stabilizable states in robust control?

Tags: dynamical-systems, matlab, control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

Let's say that we have a matrix of transfer functions:
$$G(s) = C(sI-A)^{-1}B + D$$

And we create the sensitivity matrix transfer function:

$$S(s) = (I+GK)^{-1}$$

Where $K$ is our controller gain matrix.

We also create the complementary sensitivity transfer function matrix:

$$T(s) = (I+GK)^{-1}GK$$

We also create the weighting transfer function matrices:
$$W_u(s) \\ W_T(s) \\ W_P(s)$$

You can see them as the tunning matrices. This picture below representing the $H_{ \infty}$ controller. Where $z$ is our performance output. Only for analysis. The $G$ is our transfer function matrix and $K$ is as mention before, our controller gain matrix. $w$ it's a vector of  disturbance. Notice that $\omega \neq  w$

[image]

This whole picture can be described as:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
z_1 = W_uu\\ 
z_2 = W_TGu\\ 
z_3 = W_Pw + W_PGu\\ 
v = w + Gu
\end{bmatrix}$$

And we can create our generalized plant P:

$$P = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & WuI \\ 
 0& W_TG\\ 
W_PI & WpG\\ 
I & G
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$z = Pw = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & WuI \\ 
 0& W_TG\\ 
W_PI & WpG\\ 
I & G
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
w\\ 
u 
\end{bmatrix}$$

We ca partioning the generalized plant P by saying that:

$$P = \begin{bmatrix}
P_{11} & P_{12}\\ 
 P_{21}& P_{22}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
A & B_1 & B_2\\ 
C_1 & D_{11} & D_{12} \\
C_2 & D_{21} & D_{22}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then we can say:

$$P_{11} = \begin{bmatrix}
A
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\ 
W_PI
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$P_{12} = \begin{bmatrix}
B_1 & B_2
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
W_uI\\ 
W_TG\\ 
W_PG
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$P_{21} = \begin{bmatrix}
C_1\\ 
C_2
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
I
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
P_{22} = \begin{bmatrix}
D_{11} & D_{12} \\ 
D_{21} & D_{22}
\end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix}
G
\end{bmatrix}$$

So. Now to the question! In Robust Control, it's something called detectable and stabilizable. I wonder what it are. Accoring to a book I have, this:

$$A, B_2, C_2$$

and

$$A, B_1, C_1$$

needs to be detectable and stabilizable. The definition of stabilizable is:

> A system is stabilizable if all unstable states are controllable.

The definition of detectable is:

> A system is detectable if all unstable states are observable.

I know how to find out if a system is controllable and observable. That is very easy!

To check controllibility:

$$C_o \equiv  \begin{bmatrix}
B & AB & A^2B & \dots & A^{n-1}B
\end{bmatrix}$$

And then check the rank 
$$rank(C_o) = n$$

To check observbility:

$$O_o \equiv \begin{bmatrix}
C\\ 
CA\\ 
CA^2\\
\vdots\\ 
CA^{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}$$

And then check the rank 
$$rank(O_o) = n$$

**Question:**
Do you know any formula or method to check if all unstable states are controllable and observable? Because i cannot find any states in my system which are unstable. If I find a unstable state, that means my system matrix $A$ has some positive eigenvalues? Right?

Comment: You need the Hautus test to check for stabilizability and detectability. Anyway, if you start from a transfer function representation of your system you are not going to find any unobservable/uncontrollable eigenvalues because when going from a state space representation to transfer function representation those eigenvalues drop out because they do not play a role in the input-output behaviour of your system, which is what the transfer function describes.

Comment: So you mean that I need to stick to state space representation if I want to check stability, controllbility, observbility, stabilizable and detectable. Ok! That's a good point! I found a formula about Hautus test for stabilizability https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hautus_lemma#Hautus_Lemma_for_stabilizability But the article on Wikipedia missing detectability-

Comment: There is a duality between controllability and observability. The same duality holds between detectability and stabilizability. That in combination with the article you found characterizes detectability.

Comment: So if controllbility is: $$rank[(\lambda I - A), B] = n$$ then observability must be $$rank[(\lambda I - A), C] = n$$ which lead us to stabilizability: $$rank[(\lambda I - A),B] = n$$ for every $$\lambda \in \Re \geq 0$$ And that means detectability  will be$$rank[(\lambda I - A), C] = n$$ for every $\lambda \in \Re \geq 0$$

Comment: Duality does not mean you replace $B$ by $C$. Please do a search on this first.

Comment: I have done a search for many hours from now. My book do not even tell me how to do it.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&hl=en-nl&ei=6bSZWb30HsPQwALkk4_4DA&q=duality+controllability+observability+lecture+notes&oq=duality+controllability+observability+lecture+notes&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3..33i160k1.14357.18668.0.19146.14.14.0.0.0.0.166.1706.1j13.14.0....0...1.1.64.mobile-gws-serp..0.14.1706...0i22i30k1j33i21k1.Kfx9bOEV1TA

Comment: Sorry. Did not find any good information. Only tons of equations.

Comment: Section 2.2 in the first search result tells you what duality is.

Comment: Yes. But not what I was looking for. By the way, that paper is over 50 years old. Much have change since that.

Comment: Maybe your first search result is different than mine. Anyway linear system theory hasn't really changed.

Comment: Yes it has. Pick up an old theory book about controll engineering and you will see that all have been changed. By the way. I think that no one should understand why unstable states are observable. If it not standing in my book, it will not standing on others books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you started with some wrong definitions.

The right definition for stabilizability and detectability should be:

> A system is stabilizable if the uncontrollable states are stable.
>
> A system is detectable if the unobservable states are asymptotically stable.

You seemed to be using the definition the other way around.

So with these definitions, the task should be very straightforward.

- For stabilizability, you simply decompose the system into controllable and uncontrollable subsystems, and then check if the uncontrollable subsystem is stable.
- For detectability, again, decompose the system into observable and unobservable subsystems, then check if the unobservable subsystem is asymptotically stable.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after hours of resarsch. I was looking in Essentials of Robust Control by Doyle and Zhou.

How to check if the system is stabilizable:

The matrix 
$$rank\begin{bmatrix}
(\lambda_i I-A) & B
\end{bmatrix} = n$$

has full-row rank $n$ for all eigenvalues $ \lambda_i \in \Re \geq  0$

How to check if the system is detectable:

The matrix 
$$rank\begin{bmatrix}
(\lambda_i I-A) \\ C
\end{bmatrix} = n$$

has full-row rank $n$ for all eigenvalues $ \lambda_i \in \Re \geq  0$

Comment: @MachineLearner OK. Se accepted answer

Comment: Can you edit your answer, such that I can remove my downvote?